# List comprehension on dictionary of tuples

Tags: python

Is it possible to this as a list comprehension?

```
points = []
for partial in partials:
    for point in partials[partial]:
        if point[0] == time:
            points.append(partial)
```

in python3?

Thanks,

Barry

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `for point in partial`?

Comment: This will append partial to points multiple times (as many times as there's a point which has point[0] == time).  This seems strange.

Comment: @Baz Did the behavior of `for` loops change in Python 3? I don't think it did.

Comment: The code isn't correct actually in hindsight but the answer from Sven was sufficient for me to implement the correct version as a list comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```py
points = [partial
          for partial in partials
          for point in partials[partial]
          if point[0] == time]
```

(Not sure what this is useful for, but at least this will do the same as your original code.)