# getting a list of tuples out of dictionary keys and values

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Say you have a dictionary of lists:

```
>>> a = {"a":[1, 3, 10, 2, 5], "b":[1, 0, 0, 1, 14]}
>>> a
{'a': [1, 3, 10, 2, 5], 'b': [1, 0, 0, 1, 14]}
```

From this dictionary, I would like to create another list, where each element is a (key, id) tuple, as follows:

```
>>> pairs = []
>>> for k,v in a.items():
...   for id in v:
...     pairs += [(k,id)]
... 
>>> print(pairs)
[('a', 1), ('a', 3), ('a', 10), ('a', 2), ('a', 5), ('b', 1), ('b', 0), ('b', 0), ('b', 1), ('b', 14)]
```

Is there a shortcut to do this? the previous code to create pairs is too verbose.

Comment: `[(k, id) for k in a for id in a[k]]`

Comment: Could you add an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List comprehension on dictionary of tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127017/list-comprehension-on-dictionary-of-tuples)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a double list comprehension, this goes
to the legibility however:

```
pairs = [(k, val) for k, l in a.items() for val in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done as:

```
>>> a = {"a":[1, 3, 10, 2, 5], "b":[1, 0, 0, 1, 14]}
>>> 
>>> [(k,v) for k in a for v in a[k]]
[('a', 1), ('a', 3), ('a', 10), ('a', 2), ('a', 5), ('b', 1), ('b', 0), ('b', 0), ('b', 1), ('b', 14)]
>>>
```